# DataTable Custom LINQ OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, .net-4.0, datatable

I keep getting object not set to an instance of an object and I'm not sure why.

> SortColumn datatype string Data: "123|bob", DBNull.Value, "234|sam",
>   "345|jim"

I have this so far:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(
   o => o.Field<object>(sortColumn) == 
          DBNull.Value ? 99999 : o.Field<string>(sortColumn).Split('|')[0].TryParse(0)
          ).CopyToDataTable();

public static int TryParse(this string input, int valueIfNotConverted)
{
    int value;
    if (Int32.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }
    return valueIfNotConverted;
}
```

Basically want to sort the part before | in ascending order (`CopyToDataTable()` returns the sorted table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `Field<>` extension method handles `DBNull` for you, so you can just check for a null value ([more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386916.aspx)):

```
... o.Field<object>(sortColumn) == null ? 99999 ...
```

On a side note, you can avoid the double field access by selecting all of the column values first, then doing the split:

```
table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>(sortColumn))
    .OrderBy(value => value == null ? 99999 : Convert.ToInt32(value.Split('|').First()));
```